# React: undefined the state of `this.setState` instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why I'm getting undefined if I called `console log` after `this.setState` for the same state in `componentWillMount`

this example will explain the problem

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            total: 100,
            length: null,
            number: null,
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        let JSONFetchedNumber = 30.20;
        this.setState({length: JSONFetchedNumber});
        console.log(this.state.length);// getting Null response


        let collect = this.state.total/this.state.length;
        let result = collect.toFixed(0)/1+1;
        this.setState({number: result});// This won't work cus length state in undefined
    }
  render() {
        console.log(this.state.length);// getting 30.20 Successfully
```

why I can't use the state of `this.setState` instantly in `componentWillMount`?  it works only in render

I have tried to use `componentDidMount` it wont works. Only in render works and my problem here that I can't use this.state in render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.setState is an Async function. You are trying to access it before the state is updated. So whatever manipulations you want to do on the state, you can do it in callback function.

```
this.setState({length:JSONFetchedNumber},()=>{
  //Your code which is using state
  console.log(this.state)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

this.setState is an async function, it takes time to complete. If you want to log the state, the precise way is to log it in the callback of this.setState. This should work,

```
this.setState({length: JSONFetchedNumber}, ()=> console.log(this.state.length););
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use length as a keyword in javascript, I'm pretty sure it's your error.

`var.length` is a tool in javascript to get the actual length of a variable, there must be a conflict there.